# Xcode question for writing program

Tags: objective-c, c

What is the meaning of the function `return(0);` while writing code for a simple "hello world" program ?

Comment: What's wrong with this question that it got 2 downvotes?

Comment: `return(0);` is a statement (I prefer to write it without the parenthesis: `return 0;`); not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the main function, and in which language?

If your talking about C, C++ it there is generally a return 0; at the end of any main().

Comment: in iphone application i.e.in objective-c

Comment: Then yes, quoting Vapen "That means that the program terminated fine" is the reason for the return.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the program terminated fine, as in not in an error state. I am assuming you are coding in C++.

Comment: sir it's fine.but i want to develop it in a cocoa for mac

Comment: so for that i wish to have your answers regarding tool box styles to be used for this development.